# Calculate Sum of column using groupby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I am trying to calculate my customer debt using `groupby`

I have 2 tables with the structures as you can see here :

```
  public partial class Inovice
    {
        public Inovice()
        {
            this.Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
            this.InvoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
        }
        public PersianCalendar objPersianCalender = new PersianCalendar();

        [DisplayName("شناسه")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("شناسه کاربر")]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

This table holds the customer invoices ,another tables hold the items that the customers buy.the structure is like this :

```
 public partial class InvoiceDetail
    {
        [DisplayName("شناسه ")]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("مقدار")]
        public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }   

        [DisplayName("شناسه فاکتور")]
        public int InoviceId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsReturned { get; set; }

        public virtual Inovice Inovice { get; set; }
    }
```

My values:

```
MemberOrCustomer       sumOfAmountvalues
1                        12
1                        8
2                        12
2                        11
```

These two tables has a relations on `invoiceid`.I need to sum `amount(InvoiceDetail)` values for each `memberId(Invoice)` for example :

```
MemberOrCustomer       sumOfAmountvalues
1                        20
2                        23
```

I write this code for doing this but it doesn't work :

```
 var result= invoices.GroupBy(i => i.MemberId).Select(group=>new {Amount=group.Sum(Amount)} );
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could work with a list of invoicesDetails.

```
var result = invoicesDetails.GroupBy(id => id.Invoice.MemberId)
                            .Select(g => new {
                                       MemberOrCustomer = g.Key,
                                       Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                            });
```

where invoiceDetails might be

```
invoices.SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceDetails)
```

so

```
invoices
    .SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceDetails)
    .GroupBy(id => id.Invoice.MemberId)
    .Select(g => new {
               MemberOrCustomer = g.Key,
               Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean with this code invoices.SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceDetails),should i use this ?

Comment: @EA just depending if you can work with another list than `invoices` (which would be an `IEnumerable<InvoiceDetails>` or if you need to work with `invoices`, which is an `IEnumerable<Invoice>`. See edit maybe.